# How to salt a generated hash from a file in Python

Tags: python, encryption, sign

### Problem

I wrote a function which signs an uploaded document. In order to increase the security of the function, I would like to add a [SALT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to it. As I am reading the bytes of the uploaded file, so I guess I would have to prepend or append it somehow?

### Code

This is the (working) function without SALT I currently have:

```
def sign(file):
    with open(private_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        key = f.read()
    hash = SHA256.new(file.read())
    # do signing stuff
    return signature
```

I tried to update the hash afterwards, but that does not work:

```
SALT = "random string";
def sign(file):
    with open(private_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        key = f.read()
    h = SHA256.new(file.read())
    hash = h.update(str.encode(SALT))
    # do signing stuff
    return signature
```

How could I fix this? Is there a proper standard way to do this?

Comment: Are there any error message? Or returned hash doesn't match with expected? Could you add some temp file, salt and expected result to your post? You can do simple `SHA256.new(file.read() + SALT.encode())`

Comment: `h.update()` operates in place, it doesn't return a new hash.

Comment: How would adding a salt increase security in this use case?

Comment: Basically that it makes harder to forge an identical hash of the document as it will be public. But in the best case no one will ever get the SALT.

Comment: I *highly* doubt that adding a salt will make it harder to forge a SHA256... The complete purpose of SHA256 is to prevent that, while salts are generally used to avoid duplicate password hashes in case two accounts use the same password. It has a completely different purpose.

Comment: So what do you propose as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SALT = "random string";
def sign(file):
    with open(private_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        key = f.read()
    hash_ = SHA256.new(file.read())
    hash_.update(SALT.encode())
    # do signing stuff
    return signature
```

According to the official `hashlib` documentation:

> `hash.update(data)` updates the hash object with the bytes-like object (data).

This means that `SHA256.new()` actually creates a python object, and `.update()` is a method of this python object which updates the object's property. It doesn't return anything, and hence nothing will be stored in the `hash` variable of your 2nd code.

For more information, please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155655/14850526).

Comment: Your answer is good, but consider to not use names of built-in [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)/[constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html)/[types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) in variable naming *([`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash))*, it could lead to unexpected behavior.